# RXJS: adaptative timeout

Tags: rxjs, timeout, retrywhen

I am using RXJS 6 and i trying to do a retry with adaptative timeout (i try first time with 1s timeout, if not successful i retry but with 2s timeout, etc...)

It look like the timeout value is not updated on retry, i am newbie on RxJS on i cannot find the problem.

Here the code snippet:

```
import { zip, timer, range, of, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import {  tap, retry, concatMap, timeout, catchError, delay, retryWhen } from 'rxjs/operators';

let timeoutFactor = 1;
let timeoutInit = 2000;
let timeoutValue = timeoutInit;

// simulate request
function makeRequest(timeToDelay) {  
  return of('Request Complete! '+timeToDelay).pipe(
    tap( () => console.log(`doing request (${timeToDelay}ms) with timeout of ${timeoutValue}`)),
    delay(timeToDelay));
}


const obs$ = of(4000, 3000, 2000)
  .pipe( 
    concatMap(duration => makeRequest(duration).pipe(

      timeout(timeoutValue),
      retryWhen(error => zip(error, range(1,3).pipe(
        tap( i  => {
            console.log("set timeout on " + (i*1000) + " ms")
            setTimeoutFactor(i);
          })
      )))    
    ))
  );

  obs$.subscribe(
    val => console.log(val),
    err => console.log(`err: ${err}` ),
    () => console.log(`complete` ));

  function setTimeoutFactor(value){
    timeoutValue = timeoutInit*value;
  }
```

But my result is not realy good:

```
doing request (4000ms) with timeout of 2000
set timeout on 1000 ms
set timeout on 2000 ms
set timeout on 3000 ms
doing request (4000ms) with timeout of 6000
doing request (4000ms) with timeout of 6000
doing request (4000ms) with timeout of 6000
doing request (3000ms) with timeout of 6000
timeout: 6000
Request Complete! 3000
doing request (2000ms) with timeout of 6000
timeout: 6000
Request Complete! 2000
complete
```

any help ?

Comment: Peeeerrrfffeeeccctttt :) :) :) Thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrying after a delay of your choice cannot be that complicated. For example the following (**tested working code**) sample retries after exponential delay (1s, 4s, 9s, 16s, 25s ...):

```ts
// source observable simply throws error, which is ideal for testing retry concept
const source = throwError(new Error('Oops..!'));

const smartSource = source.pipe(retryWhen(error => {
return error.pipe(mergeMap((e, i) => {
      const delayFactor = i * i *  1000;
      console.log(`Retrying after ${delayFactor / 1000} seconds`);
      return of('Retry signal').pipe(delay(delayFactor));
}));
}));

smartSource.subscribe(x => console.log('result...'));
```

If you want to change the delay logic, it is as simple as modifying the `delayFactor` according to your needs. For example if you want to retry every second:

```
const delayFactor = i * 1000;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. The answer of cartan with the use of 'retryBackoff' is more useful in my case.But i keep your answer in case of custom operator :)

Comment: i don't understand how handle Error without "timeout" operator. In your example you throw an error but in my case i can't do this. i make http call and the error need to be throw if the delay exceed. I don't need to add delay before new call i need to wait more for next call :)